# Get the average value of the pixel across all the frames

Tags: python, numpy

I have 14400 values saved in a list which represent a 4 pixels vertical by 6 pixels horizontal and 600 frames.

Here are the [values](https://www.codepile.net/pile/ZQOAgMYP) if anyone is interested

```
# len of blurry values 14400
data = np.array(blurry_values)

#shape of data (4, 6, 600)
shape = ( 4,6,600 )
data= data.reshape(shape)

#print(np.round(np.mean(data, axis=2),2))

[[0.89 0.37 0.45 0.44 0.51 0.52]
 [0.5  0.47 0.53 0.48 0.48 0.53]
 [0.49 0.5  0.5  0.53 0.48 0.54]
 [0.48 0.51 0.45 0.55 0.5  0.49]]
```

However, when I confirm the sanity of the first average by doing the following

```
list1 = blurry_values[::23]
np.round(np.mean(list1),2)
```

I get `0.51` instead of `0.89`

I am trying to get the average value of the pixel across all the frames. Why are these values different?

Comment: I'm guessing you wanted to say `::24`, not `::23`. 4 * 6 = 24

Comment: I'm guessing that you're reshaping `blurry_values` wrongly. See my answer for details, as it's difficult to convey that in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I haven't seen the code that produced `blurry_values`, I can't be 100% sure, but I'm guessing that **you're re-shaping `blurry_values` wrongly**.

In most programming scenarios, I would expect the pixel-height and pixel-width to be represented by the last two axes, and the frame to be represented by an axis preceding these two.

So, I'm guessing that your shape should have been `shape = (600, 4, 6)` instead of `shape = (4, 6, 600)`.

In that case, you should be doing `np.round(np.mean(data, axis=0),2)` rather than `np.round(np.mean(data, axis=2),2)`. BTW, that would also produce a shape of `(4, 6)`.

Then, for your **sanity check**, you should be doing this:

```
list1 = blurry_values[::24] # Note that it's 24, not 23
np.round(np.mean(list1),2)
```

You should be checking whether the first value of `np.round(np.mean(data, axis=0),2)`, with the first value of `np.round(np.mean(list1),2)`. (I haven't tested it myself, though).

Comment: Exactly this! 1) I was reshaping wrongly 2) and axis should be 0 instead of 2! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly why, but :

```
list1 = blurry_values[:600]
```

gives **0.89**

```
list1 = blurry_values[600:1200]
```

gives **0.37**

Python starts reshaping by first filling the last dimension, i believe..

Answer (score 2):

Let us tackle this with a smaller array:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

values = np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=48)
shape = (2,4,6)
data = values.reshape(shape)  # 2 frames of 4 pixels by 6 pixels each

print(data, '\n')

print(np.round(np.mean(data, axis=0),2), '\n')  # average values across frames

list1 = values[::24]
print(np.round(np.mean(list1),2))  # average of first pixel across frames
```

Output:

```
[[[51 92 14 71 60 20]
  [82 86 74 74 87 99]
  [23  2 21 52  1 87]
  [29 37  1 63 59 20]]

 [[32 75 57 21 88 48]
  [90 58 41 91 59 79]
  [14 61 61 46 61 50]
  [54 63  2 50  6 20]]] 

[[41.5 83.5 35.5 46.  74.  34. ]
 [86.  72.  57.5 82.5 73.  89. ]
 [18.5 31.5 41.  49.  31.  68.5]
 [41.5 50.   1.5 56.5 32.5 20. ]] 

41.5
```

Comment: +1, with sincere apologies. Terribly sloppy of me not to have noticed that your answer pretty much covered the same points as mine, and TWO HOURS earlier too. I don't mind deleting my answer now, it's just that I'm not sure if it's ok to delete an answer after acceptance.